# Eclipse hadoop mapreduce plugin is not working?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, mapreduce

I just have copied `hadoop-eclipse-plugin-1.0.3.jar` to the `eclipse/plugins` directory in order to get things going. But unfortunately it did not work for me. When I tried to connect eclipse to my `Hadoop Version 1.1.1` cluster it threw this error :

```
An internal error occurred during: "Map/Reduce location status updater".
org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException
```

Answer (score 1):

you get this error because there are some jars missing from the plugin which comes along with the hadoop distribution. you need to add these required jars and re-jar the plugin in order to make it work. you might find this [link](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-run-mapreduce-programs-using.html#.UUtkPzWH6IQ) helpful, wherein i have tried to show the entire procedure.